# Install IIS alongside ADFS 3.0

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, adfs, shibboleth, adfs3.0

I understand ADFS 3.0 has removed the need for IIS and that it's run directly out of HTTP.SYS now.

So does this mean it's not even possible to add IIS back so one could implement a custom FormsAuth (web forms) type integration as you used to be able to do under ADFS 2.0?

Or is it all Shibboleth these days?

**Edit:** We've been able to successfully deploy our own custom authentication provider in ADFS 3.0 (adjacent to Active Directory) and use it to SSO into Office 365 so this is no longer required. See [Implementing Office 365 single sign-on using custom authentication/claims provider in ADFS 3.0 (RE: AADSTS90019)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38860667/901156)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean can you install IIS on Server 2012 R2 to run apps., yes you can.

If you mean can you customise ADFS aspx pages as you used to be able to do, the answer is no but you can do some stuff with Javascript.

Comment: I mean install IIS on Server 2012 R2 over top of ADFS 3.0 (HTTP.SYS) to have a virtual directory on the same domain as ADFS.

Comment: Coincidentally, I've just done this and can confirm that it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can as long as the SSL bindings and routing for anything under /adfs, /federationmetadata remains the same. We've seen cases where this has not happened and resulted in the most painful of troubleshooting.

Thanks //Sam

Comment: Ugh, yes, I would strongly advise not to do it. Somehow that seems to be the issue with my configuration now - and I'm afraid I will have to reinstall everything.